# Best way to have a web user interface for a Qt application?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, web

I have written a service using C++ and Qt framework (QtService). The service should run in the background. I need the service to have a web user interface and can be accessed using web browsers. I mean the service should act as as a web server and output html content to a specific port. I know there are some frameworks that can be used to generate web content in C++, but by taking into account that I am using Qt, I prefer to use Qt features as much as possible rather than a new framework. Any ideas?

Comment: web user interface written in C++?

Comment: You mean you want your application to incorporate a web browser, or you want your application to act as a local web server?

Comment: @Мартин Бее, yes. Of course, preferably using Qt framework.

Comment: @MrEricSir, I clarified my question. I need my application to act as a web server (not necessarily local).

Answer (score 2):

I have read about [Cutelyst](http://cutelyst.org/) on the Qt blog a few times, which seems an exact fit to your question.